# AWK/Bash script trying to parse some file names

Tags: xml, bash, shell, awk

I am trying to parse a "README" file that will contain 1 or 2 lines, the lines are either "index" and/or "required." They are followed by a ":" delimiter and file names, for example:

index:index.html
required:file2.1:file2.2

Index and required files are parsed and put into an xml document. So I have  being created if there is an index line and vice versa for required. Here are my awk scripts:

// for index
awk -F":" 'NR==1{ for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) print "        "$i"" >> myfile }' myfile="$1/dir.xml" $1/README;

// for required
awk -F":" 'NR==2{ for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) print "        "$i"" >> myfile }' myfile="$1/dir.xml" $1/README;

My problem is that not all readme files contain an index line and causes required to be line one, and my required script looks for line 2, is there a better way of doing this? I need my required section to parse required even if index line is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than checking for `NR==1` check for value in first field like this:

```
awk -F":" '$1 == "index"{
   for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) print " "$i"" >> myfile }' myfile="$1/dir.xml" $1/README

awk -F":" '$1 == "required"{ 
   for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) print " "$i"" >> myfile }' myfile="$1/dir.xml" $1/README
```

Comment: Thanks! cant believe I didn't figure that one out hah.